# AWS EBS(Elastic Block Store) vs EFS(Elastic File System) communication with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

It might be a noob question but couldn't find anything solid on the web so here I go.

I know that both EBS (Elastic Block Store) and EFS (Elastic File System) communicate with EC2 over the network (data transmission). To make an EFS work with EC2, I read that traffic on the NFS port must be allowed by the inbound security group (attached to EC2 instance).

But, I don't think any such configuration is required for EBS. So, why we don't need any configuration for EBS and yet it works?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Amazon EBS volumes** attach to Amazon EC2 instances as devices via a separate network connection to the host computer. It does *not* attach via a VPC, so Security Groups are not available.

Amazon EBS volumes are bandwidth restrictions on Amazon EBS volumes, which vary by Volume Type. See: [Amazon EBS volume types - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html)

Older Amazon EC2 instance types could increase bandwidth to EBS volumes by using [Amazon EBS Optimization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html) that uses "an optimized configuration stack and provides additional, dedicated capacity for Amazon EBS I/O". Modern EC2 instances have this enabled by default.

In contrast, **Amazon EFS** is attached to instances via a VPC, so Security Group rules apply.

Comment: In (very bad) layman's terms, think of Amazon EBS as a directly-attached disk and EFS as a network-attached volume. Or, as SAN vs NAS.